# Arrange $F_1$, $F_2$ and $F_3$ in descending order

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, coulombs-law, dielectric

[image]

In case 1 the medium is air and Q1 and Q2 are point charges. I thought that force will be inversely related to the dielectric constant so I thought F1>F2>F3 but that's not that the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

The potential in (b) is due to an effective dipole (polarization charge) from $q_1$, as considering the force from it on $q_2$, and in (c) the field internal to the dielectric due to its polarization is zero, and so we simply have $F_3 \lt F_1$, according to K.